# convert tailwincss to normal CSS?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have been given an html file that is written using tailwindcss and I am trying to figure out how to convert all there stuff to normal CSS. I have found a convert that will just do the class but that requires me to extract thousands of classes from the code manually and then repast it. Is there some tool where I can just upload the whole html file and it spit out a CSS version of it for me or do I have to manually do this whole conversion? I would prefer something online as I don't want to go though having to install a bunch of 3rd party tools, learning there system, do the convert, and then uninstall everything.

Comment: Can you paste a link to the html file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Paste your `html code` in [`tailwind-playground`](https://play.tailwindcss.com/)

##### You can access the css in the **`generated css files`** tab.

Example

[image]

According to [tailwind-css docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight)

> Tailwind automatically injects these styles when you include @tailwind base in your CSS (*the first 552 lines of generated css*)

You can remove those base classes by setting `preflight = false` in `tailwind.config.cs`

```
module.exports = {
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this tool: https://tailwind-to-css.vercel.app/ for converting the tailwind CSS class to normal CSS.

Comment: That is the tool I talked about. I ahve to manually extract all the classes for that to work I can't just paste the HTML doc on there and get it convertred. It would take me hours to extract every single tailwindCSS, convert it and past it back in.

Comment: It not recognize the hover: classes :(

Comment: Doesn't recognize custom classes like `min-h-[150px]`